# I need to assign each person a room number, but it assigns it with each index number

Tags: ruby

```
def assign_rooms (array) 
  room_number = (1..7).to_a
  attendees.map.each_with_index { |attendees, room_number|
    "Hello, #{attendees}! You'll be assigned to room #{room_number}!"
  }
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need an explanation of the problem, and your intended behavior _in the question_. Also, it's really important to format your question correctly. Failing to do that slows and/or discourages answers to you. Look at a random sampling of other SO questions and you'll figure out the style. There's help built into the edit box for entering text when creating your question.

Comment: Instead of `map.each_with_index` use `map.with_index`.

Answer (score 2):

Within your `each_with_index` block you have assigned the `index` value to the local variable `room_number`. I'm guessing you want to do something like this:

```
attendees.map.with_index { |attendee, index| "Hello, #{attendee}!
   You'll be assigned to room #{room_number[index]}!" }
```

With this you will be matching up each `attendee` to the value from `room_number` that corresponds to the `index` value of the loop.

This won't work out too well if you have more `attendees` than `room_number`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def assign_rooms (attendees) 
  attendees.map.with_index do |attendee, room_number|
    "Hello, #{attendee}! You'll be assigned to room #{room_number + 1 }!"
  end
end

array = ['steve', 'john']
p assign_rooms(array)

#=> ["Hello, steve! You'll be assigned to room 1!", "Hello, john! You'll be assigned to room 2!"]
```

Here we're mapping a new array and using the indices of the `array` to make the room numbers. Seeing as room numbers are generally never `0`, we add `1` to each `room_number`.